# Ошибка MySql при поиске на сайте

Tags: mysql, битрикс

Перенесли сайт на новый VDS сервер. Пытаемся воспользоваться поиском, переходит на страницу поиска и пишет `DB query error.`и код

```
MySQL Query Error: SELECT sct.SEARCH_CONTENT_ID ,scsite.SITE_ID ,match sct.SEARCHABLE_CONTENT against('(FM*)' in boolean mode) RANK FROM b_search_content_text sct INNER JOIN b_search_content sc ON sc.ID = sct.SEARCH_CONTENT_ID INNER JOIN b_search_content_site scsite ON sc.ID = scsite.SEARCH_CONTENT_ID WHERE ((1=1)) AND (match sct.SEARCHABLE_CONTENT against('(FM*)' in boolean mode)) AND ( ( scsite.SITE_ID = 's1') AND( ( sc.MODULE_ID = 'iblock' AND sc.PARAM1 = '1c_catalog' AND sc.PARAM2 = '16' )) ) ORDER BY sc.CUSTOM_RANK DESC, RANK DESC, sc.DATE_CHANGE DESC[[1214] The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes]
```

Как можно будет это поправить? Ранее поиск работал!

Comment: Очевидно что у вас сейчас тип таблиц, которые в данной конкретной версии MySQL не поддерживают FULLTEXT.

Comment: Хоть бы что-нибудь поискали прежде чем вопросы писать. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964269/1214-the-used-table-type-doesnt-support-fulltext-indexes/20964330#20964330